# WPF binding OneWayToSource sets source property to "" when the DataContext is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a OneWayToSource binding that is not behaving as I expected when I set the DataContext of the target control. The property of the source is being set to default instead of the value of the target control's property.

I've created a very simple program in a standard WPF window that illustrates my problem:

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox x:Name="tb"
    Text="{Binding Path=Text,Mode=OneWayToSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>

  <Button Content="Set DataContext" Click="Button1_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   private ViewModel _vm = new ViewModel();

   private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      Debug.Print("'Set DataContext' button clicked");
      tb.DataContext = _vm;
   }

   private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      Debug.Print("TextBox changed to " + tb.Text);
   }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel
{
   private string _Text;
   public string Text
   {
      get { return _Text; }
      set
      {
         Debug.Print(
            "ViewModel.Text (old value=" + (_Text ?? "<null>") + 
            ", new value=" + (value ?? "<null>") + ")");
         _Text = value;
      }
   }
}
```

The TextBox `tb` starts out with a null DataContext and therefore the binding is not expected to do anything. So if I type something in the text box, say "X", the ViewModel.Text property remains null.

If I then click the **Set DataContext** button I would have expected the `ViewModel.Text` property to be set to the "X" of the `TextBox.Text` property. Instead it is set to "". Certainly the binding is working because if I then type "Y" in the text box, after the "X", it sets the `ViewModel.Text` property to "XY".

Here is an example of the output (the last two lines are counter-intuitive because of the order of evaluation, but they definitely both occur immediately after typing the "Y"):

> TextBox changed to X
>   'Set DataContext' button clicked
>   ViewModel.Text (old value=<null>, new value=)
>   ViewModel.Text (old value=, new value=XY)
>   TextBox changed to XY

Why is the `ViewModel.Text` property being set to "" instead of "X" when the DataContext is set?

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Have I misunderstood something about binding?

**Edit**: I would have expected the output to be:

> TextBox changed to X
>   'Set DataContext' button clicked
>   ViewModel.Text (old value=<null>, new value=**X**)
>   ViewModel.Text (old value=**X**, new value=XY)
>   TextBox changed to XY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bug or perhabs not. Microsoft claims its by design. You first type x and then you kill DataContext by clicking on Button hence why the TextBox holds x and your viewModel.Text property gets newly initialized (its empty). When on datacontext changed getter will still be called. In the end you have no chance to fix this.

You can however use two way and let it be.

Comment: I may have to use TwoWay and "let it be" as you say. Do you have a link to Microsoft's "it's by design" argument?

Comment: the point here is that you have wrong impression about one way to source binding. it is not doing what you expect or better said you lack on binding knowledge. if you take a look at documentation about bindings you will notice that binding creates a bridge between target and source but also immediately sets a value to target since target is initializing the binding in first place. therefore no matter if two way or one way the binding will always ask for getter. take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579238/wpf-binding-onewaytosource-property-get-method-was-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

TextBox has a Binding in it's TextProperty and when you set  TextBox's DataContext, TextBox will update it's source (viewmodel.Text) , no matter which type of the UpdateSourceTrigger.

It's said that the first output in viewmodel

"`ViewModel.Text (old value=<null>, new value=)`"

is not triggered by `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

It's just a process of init:

```
private string _Text;
public string Text
{
    get { return _Text; }
    set
    {
        Debug.Print(
           "ViewModel.Text (old value=" + (_Text ?? "<null>") +
           ", new value=" + (value ?? "<null>") + ")");
        _Text = value;
    }
}
```

Because it's not triggered by `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, the viewmodel will not know the value of TextBox.Text.

When you type "Y",the trigger of PropertyChanged will working,so the viewmodel read text of TextBox.

Comment: This would certainly achieve the end result but it seems a bit cumbersome and would have to be done for each such binding. Also, it causes the ViewModel property to be set twice (although I have a gut feeling that *that* can't be avoided).

Comment: @stritch000 remove `tb.Text = "";`  it will not causes the ViewModel property to be set twice

Comment: That makes no difference. It still gets set twice.

Comment: @stritch000 so, what's your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you will have to `UpdateSource` like below:

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {

      Debug.Print("'Set DataContext' button clicked");
      tb.DataContext = _vm;
      var bindingExp = tb.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
      bingExp.UpdateSource();
   }
```

Comment: This looks promising but it doesn't work. It just sets the ViewModel.Text to "" a second time.

Comment: @stritch000 may I know why do you have this particular requirement of setting DataContext of textbox on button click? There must be elegant way of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in .NET 4 with one way to source bindings that it calls getter for OneWayToSource bindings thats why you are having this problem.You can verify it by putting breakpoint on   tb.DataContext = _vm; you will find setter is called and just after that getter is called on Text property.You can resolve your problem by manually feeding the viewmodel values from view before assigning the datacontext..NET 4.5 resolves this issue.
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875751/onewaytosource-binding-seems-broken-in-net-4-0) and [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967667/wpf-net-4-onewaytosource-binding-to-write-only-property-works-on-some-machine)

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.Print("'Set DataContext' button clicked");       
    _vm.Text=tb.Text;
    tb.DataContext = _vm;
}
```

Comment: Neither of those links are the same issue (and not fixed in 4.5). My issue is that the ViewModel.Text property is being set to empty **when the data context is being changed**. The binding otherwise works fine.

Comment: Because the getter is called as soon as you apply data context and text value of view is updated to _Text of vm which is null.You still see the old value in UI as there is no event to refresh it.You can verify this by changing binding to Two way and it will become null as soon as you press the button.Since its a One way binding getter should not be called(which is the bug).You can use my proposed code in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need `Attached property`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty OneWaySourceRaiseProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("OneWaySourceRaise", typeof(object), typeof(FrameworkElementExtended), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OneWaySourceRaiseChanged));

        public static object GetOneWaySourceRaise(DependencyObject o)
        {
            return o.GetValue(OneWaySourceRaiseProperty);
        }

        public static void SetOneWaySourceRaise(DependencyObject o, object value)
        {
            o.SetValue(OneWaySourceRaiseProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OneWaySourceRaiseChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue == null)
                return;

            var target = (FrameworkElement)d;
            target.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            var bindings = target.GetBindings().Where(i => i.ParentBinding?.Mode == BindingMode.OneWayToSource).ToArray();
            foreach (var i in bindings)
            {
                i.DataItem.SetProperty(i.ParentBinding.Path.Path, d.GetValue(i.TargetProperty));
            }
        });
```

And set binding in XAML:

```
extendends:FrameworkElementExtended.OneWaySourceRaise="{Binding}"
```

where `{Binding}` - is binding to `DataContext`.
You need:

```
    public static IEnumerable<BindingExpression> GetBindings<T>(this T element, Func<DependencyProperty, bool> func = null) where T : DependencyObject
            {
                var properties = element.GetType().GetDependencyProperties();
                foreach (var i in properties)
                {
                    var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(element, i);
                    if (binding == null)
                        continue;
                    yield return binding;
                }
            }


private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, DependencyProperty[]> DependencyProperties = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, DependencyProperty[]>();
    public static DependencyProperty[] GetDependencyProperties(this Type type)
            {
                return DependencyProperties.GetOrAdd(type, t =>
                {
                    var properties = GetDependencyProperties(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type, new Attribute[] { new PropertyFilterAttribute(PropertyFilterOptions.All) }));
                    return properties.ToArray();
                });
            }

            private static IEnumerable<DependencyProperty> GetDependencyProperties(PropertyDescriptorCollection collection)
            {
                if (collection == null)
                    yield break;
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor i in collection)
                {
                    var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(i);
                    if (dpd == null)
                        continue;
                    yield return dpd.DependencyProperty;
                }
            }
```